# jQuery $.post data assign to vaiable if more than 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling data from MySQL using jquery $.post

```
var fruitInfo ='';
$.post('test.php',
        {
          b:'fruits'
        },
        function(data){
          //console.log(data[0]['val1']);
          for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
              //if data[0]['appleStocks'] is not 0 -> `fruitInfo` += '<p>appleStocks</p>'
              //if data[0]['grapesStocks'] is not 0 -> `fruitInfo` += '<p>grapesStocks</p>'
              //check if custom data is not 0 add to `fruitInfo`
          }
        });
```

My question is, I need to add certain field values received in to `fruitInfo` if the returned value is not 0. Should these custom fields be stored in an array to be checked? How should I do this?

ex:
The php returns the

```
storeNumber = 123, 
grapeTypes = a,b,
AppleTypes = b,
LycheeTypes = a,b,
grapeStocks = 91,
appleStocks = 0,
lycheeStocks = 25,
```

By using `(data[0]['grapeStocks']`, `data[0]['appleStocks']` and `data[0]['lycheeStocks']` I want to be able to update var `fruitInfo` as below

```
fruitInfo = '<p>grapeStocks = 91, lycheeStocks = 25</p>';
```

Comment: how do you identify which one is fruit and which one isn't?

Comment: @gurvinder372: Thanks. As in my example accessing `(data[0]['grapeStocks']`, `data[0]['appleStocks']` and `data[0]['lycheeStocks']` from the returned values

Comment: @gurvinder372 Should I store grapeStocks, appleStocks, etc... in an array and use foreach ?

Comment: yeah something similar, try the answer I have given below

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop inside the callback handler to

```
     var fruits = {"appleStocks" : 0, "grapesStocks" : 0};
     for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {

          if (data[0]['appleStocks'] > 0 ){ fruits[appleStocks] += data[0]['appleStocks'] }
          else if (data[0]['grapesStocks'] > 0 ){ fruits[grapesStocks] += data[0]['grapesStocks'] }
     }
     var fruitInfo = "<p>" + Object.keys(fruits).map(function(value){return key + "=" + fruits[key];}).join(" , ") + "</p>" ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. :) If there are 15 values to check writing else if would take some time. Any solution for this? +10

Comment: @Becky since your response have other values also, this way seems to be fine.